# ColdFusion - how do I execute an SQL "IN" clause in cfscript?

Tags: sql, coldfusion

How would I construct an IN clause in cfscript? Here's what I have:

```
var tagList = "301,302,303,304";
var q = new Query ();
q.setDatasource ("mydatasource");

var sqlStmt = "SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE tagID IN (:tagList)";

// I know the next line is not correct!
q.addParam (name="tagList", value="#tagList#", cfsqltype="??? WHAT SHOULD IT BE ???");
```

Is there an easy way to do this, or do I need to iterate through the list of tags, adding each one separately?

Comment: Small point - CF sometimes gets funny about parameters.  Tends to need a trailing space after the param name, has caused me issues in the past (so `( :tagList )` for example) (http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1678-Learning-ColdFusion-9-Using-CFQuery-And-Other-Service-Tags-In-CFScript.htm)

Comment: I haven't noticed this behavior, but that's a good article. Thanks!

Comment: It's most commonly seen when someone decides it's a good idea to trim all whitespace, leading and trailing, and that then trims trailing spaces.  Following getting that cleared up, the workaround we now use is to just surround all params with brackets (as shown for your IN) so the trailing space never gets counted as trailing by that silly cleanup script :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a list attribute on `<cfqueryparam>` which ought to be supported:

```
q.addParam (name="tagList", value="#tagList#", cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER", list="yes");
```

Comment: Ah ha! I'll try it and post back!